# Modules not visible in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

[image: folder structure]

**My .xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config>
 <modules>
  <TutsPlus_Demo>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
  </TutsPlus_Demo>
  </modules>
  </config>
```

It is not visible in admin panel under System->Advanced->modules

And the xml is located under app->Etc->modules

Comment: Is your .xml file located under > app/etc/modules/TutsPlus_Demo.xml ?

Comment: check on github repo  https://github.com/vishalpardeshi/magento_E-com_Application/tree/master/app/code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Log out from Magento admin panel or clean session. And after that please login again.

Comment: Clear session from database or clear browser session. I have cleared browse session but solution won't work

Comment: Try to clean cache.
System->Cache Management and check please "Configuration" and push Submit button.

Comment: System->Cache Management and check please "Configuration"  its work for me

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

1. Your xml file should be in `app/etc/modules/`
2. xml file name should be `TutsPlus_Demo.xml`
3. Check your compiler , if its enable then disable it from `system->Tools->Compilation`

Comment: The complier status is disabled. But then also now not showing in advance. Are any tutorial for magenta from scratch.

Comment: is there any extra space in folder name ?

Comment: No space but the local folder was not available I have created it. Manually.

Comment: check on github repo  https://github.com/vishalpardeshi/magento_E-com_Application/tree/master/app/code